# Memory allocation limit on C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

I want to run this huge C++ project that uses up to 8.3 GB in memory. Can I run this program under certain circumstances or is it impossible ?

Comment: This is a slightly confusing question. If you know it uses 8.3GB then you must know that it runs.

Comment: no .. i have calculated how much memory it should use. if i run it, it says bad alloc, so i have to extend that memory limit somehow.

Comment: Then you don't really know what the program uses - but the size of the data set you want you're program to operate on.

Comment: It seems you have already implemented a test for this use case, if not you should. Then minimize the code if necessary and edit it into your question. I also suggest updating the tags to reflect what your target platform is. There is a huge different in how memory is manager on Linux as opposed to Windows. If you make those updates you might get an actual solution to your problem.

Answer (score 7):

It's fine.  You just need to be on a 64-bit architecture, and ensure that there's sufficient swap space + physical memory available

Answer (score 5):

It really depends. If the program needs to have all the 8.3 GB in memory all the time ([working size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_set_size)), you may need to have a similar amount of memory installed in your computer.

Let's now assume you have 4 GB of RAM. In such a case you will be most probably able to execute the program thanks to the use of [swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) (hard disk area where memory is swapped in and out with the intention of enlarging the virtual memory size). But, even if it may actually work, it could run really slow (up to the point that is not really usable) because of [trashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29).

On the other hand, if your program processes 8.3 GB of data, but it is processed in smaller *chunks*, that will mean that all the data is not in memory all the time. Then, you will not need to have installed such a big amount of RAM in your computer.

As Oli Charlesworth was mentioning you will need a 64-bit system (both the hardware and OS) <strike>or, at least, a system with [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) capabilities if you want to install more than 4 GB of RAM in your system</strike>.

Comment: PAE is not going to help you: each program is still limited to 4GB of memory even though the OS can use more.

Comment: @Yexo Yes, you are right. In this case PAE would be useless since the OP seems to be asking for a single application (process). I fixed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. You need to be in a 64-bit environment and, of course, have the RAM available. You may still be unable to allocate more than 4gb of contiguous address space at a time. It's possible that you'll have to allocate it in smaller chunks, though.